# Angular 2 correct way to get data from server

Tags: forms, angular, http

I want to get data from the database. I'm following the examples at angular.io webpage but I don't know if I'm doing right.

I have a form and when a user fills the postal code field, I call the database to get the name of the city or, if it doesn't exist, ask the user to fill it.
My problem is I don't know how to correctly do it.

In my service.

```
checkCp(city: City): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.backendUrl + 'api/city/' + city.cp).pipe(
    tap(city => console.log("fetched"))      
  );
}
```

and this is in my component.js

```
checkCp(): void {
  this.modal.header = 'Searching city';
  this.modal.text = 'Please wait';
  this.openWaitModal();
  this.studentService.checkCp(this.city)
    .subscribe(cityFromDb => {
      if(cityFromDb ===null) {
        this.closeWaitModal();
        this.modal.header = 'Postal code not found';
        this.modal.text = 'Insert the name of the city';
        this.modal.no = 'Cancel';
        this.modal.yes = 'Insert';
        this.modal.action = 'newCity';
        this.modal.enableInput = true;
        this.openModal();
      }else{        
        this.closeWaitModal();        
        this.city = cityFromDb.city; // I can't access cityFromDb.name
                                     // i access via cityFromDb.city.name
     }
   }, err => {
     this.errorHandler(err);
   })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would call your service as follows:

```
checkCp(city: City): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.backendUrl + 'api/city/' + city.cp);
};
```

This will return an `Observable` to your component.ts

The code in your component.ts should work now

Comment: No problem, enjoy Angular!

Comment: Is correct to access the properties this way cityFromDb.city.name instead of access cityFromDb.name ?

Comment: It all depends on how you've structured the json object that is coming back from the server